# Cant create kernel arg,program exit

Tags: c++11, parallel-processing, opencl

I am trying to create kernel argument for a structure,but after executing `clSetKernelArg` line,program exit the system.

```
predict_component=(component *)malloc(sizeof(component)*component_count);
predict_component_mem=clCreateBuffer(al_context,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,sizeof(component)*component_count,predict_component,&al_status);
al_status =  clSetKernelArg(al_kernel[0], 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&predict_component_mem);
```

**component is a basic structure.

I am totally unable to locate the cause,any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: how does your CL kernel code looks like?

Comment: What's the return error code of `clSetKernelArg` and `clCreateBuffer`?